# Navigationbar not showing current page number

Tags: iphone, ios6, indexing, uinavigationbar, uipageviewcontroller

Navigation bar is not showing current page number.

It is showing 0 of 8. whereas it should show 1 of 8.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

//modelArray holds the page numbers
modelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int index = 1; index <= totalPages; index++) {

[modelArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index]];

}

_navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 45)];

_navBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:164.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

UINavigationItem *title = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                                   @"Page %i of %i",
                                                                  index,
                                                                   CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument)]];
[_navBar pushNavigationItem:title animated:NO];

thePageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

thePageViewController.delegate = self;
thePageViewController.dataSource = self;

thePageViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithPDF:PDFDocument];
contentViewController.page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:contentViewController];
[thePageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:thePageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:thePageViewController.view];
thePageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

[thePageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

//self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor underPageBackgroundColor];
[self.view addSubview:_navBar];
}
```

Tried using currentIndex and pageNumber instead of just using index. With just using index it shows 46297464 of 8 and when i use currentIndex or pageNumber it shows 0 of 8. Whereas it should show 1 of 8.

And that is how i m using pageviewcontroller datasource methods

```
  - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
  viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithPDF:PDFDocument];

currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)viewController page]];

if (currentIndex == 0) {

    return nil;

}

contentViewController.page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex - 1];

return contentViewController;

  }

 - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
   viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithPDF:PDFDocument];

//get the current page
currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)viewController page]];


if (currentIndex == totalPages - 1) {

    return nil;

}

contentViewController.page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex + 1];

return contentViewController;

   }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: how are you assigning totalPages variable ?

Comment: int currentIndex;
    int totalPages;  i just tried this - (void) pageViewController:(PageViewController *)pageViewController willTurnToPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)pageIndex {
    
    if (title == [NSString stringWithFormat:
                        @"Page %u of %u",
                        currentIndex,
                        CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument)]){
        
        
        [currentIndex + 1];
    }

}
 i m sure coding is not right but all i want is that when user turns to next page then navigation bar should update the current pagenumber in the title

Comment: @"Page %i of %i",
index,
CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument)]]; if you see the variable index, where it is defined ? i guess it you should have some reference outside your for loop to save the value of index